# Pass hidden ID when textbox is changed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have multiple textboxes, every textbox has a related hidden field, the hidden field's ID is a concatenation of a string with the model's ID (ex: "`FormState25`")

How can I pass the ID of a hidden field when a textbox being changed? I'm using the following code to detect textbox change:

```
$("#body-content-container").on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
    $("#FormState").val('dirty');
});
```

Comment: Where do you want to pass the ID?  Back to the controller?

Comment: I want to change the value of the hidden field first, for example, from 'Unchanged' to 'Modified' using Javascript before submitting the form to the controller.

Comment: Is the ID coming from your text input element?  Is it "25" in this case?

Comment: what do you want to do with holding state of boxes?let me know to help you.

Comment: No, these textboxes represent the children of a main object, their id's are like: `VehicleModels_56998496-6f3f-4667-9c6b-339895b67c58__Name`

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili I have VehicleTypes which has a collection of VehicleModels, they are displayed on a form and intended to be saved by on call, each object of VehicleModels has a textbox and a hidden field that holds the object's state ('Unchanged', 'Added') I want to get the hidden Id when a textbox has changed so that I can change the hidden field's value before submitting the form to the controller.

Comment: changing corresponding hidden field when an input changed.is this what you want?

Comment: ok.i got it.what is pattern of hidden filed id then?

Comment: oh! i saw it. "FormState" + InputID

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili It's a concatenation of a string with the VehicleModel's Id ex: "FormState25"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom attributes to the textbox tag itself that includes the Id of the hidden field, for example:

**In View**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { HiddenFieldId = "FormState" + Model.Id })
```

This way when a textbox get changed you can get the Id of the hidden field you already use to store whatever you want, and then modify the javascript to handle that hidden field's Id, like this:

**Javascript**

```
$("#body-content-container").on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
    var hiddenId = $(this).attr("HiddenFieldId");
    $("#" + hiddenId).val('dirty');
});
```

The javascript will get the `HiddenFieldId` attribute of the corresponding hidden field from the textbox and change it's value. Try this and let me know..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` to reference the element on which the anonymous function is defined, e.g.:

```
$("#body-content-container").on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
    $("#FormState" + this.attr('id')).val('dirty');
});
```

Comment: The textbox's Id is not a sub of the hidden field's Id

Comment: Well, you need to tie them together somehow.  If you have a standard naming convention for your IDs, then you should be able to find relevant string as a substring.  Better yet, if you are constructing the elements in a loop you can use the loop index to construct the IDs.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function(){
     var hiddenId = "FormState" + $(this).attr("Id");
     var hiddenField = $("#" + hiddenId);
     hiddenField.val("dirty");
});
```

**EDIT:**

if your hidden field rendered just after your inputbox then you can do the following :

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function(){        
     var hiddenField = $(this).next();
     hiddenField.val("dirty");
});
```

hope this could help.

Comment: The problem is that the texbox id is different than the hidden field's id, because the texbox is created using TextboxFor extension and the hidden field is not a property of the model so it's being created using Hidden extension, so the resulting id's are like: `VehicleModels_56998496-6f3f-4667-9c6b-339895b67c58__Name` and `FormState25` respectfully for textbox and hidden field

Comment: how about preceding text boxes with hidden fields?this has lower time complexity for searching element as well!

Comment: is the order of inputbox and hidden sequential?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another trick which I've used in the past.  Enclose the two related input fields in a `div` (or other) element.  Then use the fact that the text field and the hidden field are siblings to select the correct hidden field.  Perhaps something like this (NOTE: I have not tested this example):

```
<div id="someId">
  <input type="hidden" value="unchanged" />
  <input type="text" value="some data" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var hiddenInput = $('#someId input:first')
  var textInput = $('#someId input:last')

  textInput.on('change', function() {
    hiddenInput.val('modified');
  });
</script>
```